# Need to install clang into MSVC

Tags: c++, clang

I already downloaded and installed Clang. How can I set it up on MSVC without downloading it again?

I have search the internet to no avail. It just tells me how to install via internet. I don't have a direct internet access to my computer. I just begged someone to use my desktop at their place and completely forgot to test that my Microsoft Visual Studio install is up and running. It is installed but no CPP compilers. Only C#.

As I said, I already installed clang. I am kindly asking how can I let my MSVC install be aware of this fact. I really don't have any internet connection. My phone data cannot download these stuff.

Comment: You might have to go and beg for some more free internet.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Clang *only* with Visual Studio. You also need Microsoft's headers and standard library files.

So out of luck, unless you can find some internet connection again.

Comment: Is there a way to download to a thumbdrive and install offline. My main problem is that I don't have internet connection at home to connect to my desktop. I can always travel to a place with internet to download the required files. Problem is I don't see any options in MSVC to connect offline compiler. I already have a clang compiler which I want to use with MSVC. And I don't know how to use clang from the command line

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I'm lucky enough to have a fast internet connection and have not tried anything else. And using clang from the command line wouldn't help either, as it has not re-implemented [the C++ standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header) for Windows, but is using the Microsoft files. So you would need these anyway.

Comment: Thank you anyhow.